# Log4Net and Application Insights-no data is coming through

Tags: c#, azure-application-insights

I'm using Log4Net in my my C# console application and want the logged events to appear in Application Insights as well.

I've added Application Insights as well as the Application Insights Log4Net Appender.

I've followed the instructions here: https://jan-v.nl/post/using-application-insights-in-your-log4net-application with no luck.

Log4Net is logging fine. However, when I go to the Application Insights dashboard, I see this: "THE APPLICATION HAS NO DATA IN APPLICATION INSIGHTS."

At the beginning of my main cs file, I've got this:

```
var telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient { InstrumentationKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["applicationInsights"] };
```

at the end, there is this:

```
telemetryClient.Flush();
```

In my app.config file, I have this:

```
 <log4net>
    <root>
      <level value="INFO" />
      <appender-ref ref="FileAppender" />
      <appender-ref ref="aiAppender" />
    </root>
    <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
      <file value="C:\logs\logfile.txt" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] – %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="aiAppender" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Log4NetAppender.ApplicationInsightsAppender, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Log4NetAppender">
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
  </log4net>
```

When I run the application, I see this sort of thing in the output window:

```
Application Insights Telemetry (unconfigured): {"name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Message","time":"2017-07-04T10:26:15.7741453Z","tags":{"ai.internal.sdkVersion":"log4net:2.2.0-220","ai.cloud.roleInstance":"xxx","ai.user.id":"AzureAD\\xxx"},"data":{"baseType":"MessageData","baseData":{"ver":2,"message":"xxx","severityLevel":"Information","properties":{xxx"}}}}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Is the AI instrumentation key in app.config?

Comment: Yes, it is. *filler characters here*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ApplicationInsights has evolved since this question was asked.  The original static TelemetryConfiguration.Active is now obsolete for various reasons.  Those still trying to get their log4net config up quickly can do this (in their log4net configuration file):

```
<appender name="aiAppender" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Log4NetAppender.ApplicationInsightsAppender, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Log4NetAppender">
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%message%newline" />
  </layout>
  <threshold value="INFO" />
  <InstrumentationKey value="12345678-7946-1234-1234-8b330fbe1234" />
</appender>
```

Comment: For my own app, I actually evolved this to copy/alter the ApplicationInsightsAppender locally to allow me to set the TelemetryClient via code at startup.  I wanted to be able to set the user/session/... values and not have the appender & telemetry bits in the app going over two different telemetry channels with their own sessionIDs.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without having to paste the instrumentation key in your log4net config?

Comment: @Enrico If it's not in your l4n config file, where would you like the key to be?

Comment: It should be in your appsettings. I figured it out and updated my answer

Comment: @Enrico your solution presumes IOC, which I wouldn't say is quite universal in the WPF world these days. Yea, I'd love to have every setting in one file, but if you're going to have a log4net config file in the first place, it's not the worst to have the instrumentation key there too.

Comment: Very true, but log4net is not only used in WCF applications.

Answer (score 2):

Log4Net AI appender will not use the TelemtryClient you create.

Set AI Instrumentation Key like this:

```
TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["applicationInsights"];
```

See, https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet-logging

Comment: Because the logging packages don't know anything about your `TelemetryClient` instance.  It is entirely possible for a single app (or website, or whatever) to send different kinds of telemetry to different ikeys, so in your example, you've created a "private" telemetry client where your code is the only thing that knows about that specific ikey.  The logging ones use the shared configuration from `TelemetryConfiguration.Active` to send data to that common place.

Comment: This method has been marked obsolete:  We do not recommend using TelemetryConfiguration.Active on .NET Core. See https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/1152 for more details

Answer (score 1):

Applies to **dotnetcore 2.2** and **Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights 2.10**

I also had an issue that my loggings were not send to AI. After looking for a long time. I came on this path after i had seen that in debugging my calls to AI and the telemetry channel were executed, but when just running the api, no data was sent.

I found out it had something to do with the Telemetry Channel that is used (look in the online documention of microsoft what the telemetry channel, but it acts as a middleware between your application and azure application insight).

If you are working on a DEV machine (no SERVERS!), you can set this flag to true

In StartUp.ConfigureServices:

```
#if DEBUG
            TelemetryConfiguration.Active.TelemetryChannel.DeveloperMode = true;
#endif
```

And after that all my logging were sent to AI, and could be found in traces table, and can be seen for each request.

I found the answer on their GIT page: https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/964

Another note: the default level is Warning, to set this to a lower level, add this to program.cs

```
    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseApplicationInsights()
            .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
            {                
                // Optional: Apply filters to configure LogLevel Trace or above is sent to
                // ApplicationInsights for all categories.
                logging.AddFilter<ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider>("", LogLevel.Trace);

                // Additional filtering For category starting in "Microsoft",
                // only Warning or above will be sent to Application Insights.
                logging.AddFilter<ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider>("Microsoft", LogLevel.Warning);

            })
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

Comment: Also may be worth setting a delay before that app quits to ensure the data is flushed.  I found this with webjobs that even force flushing app insights does not guarantee it will flush through to AI servers.  I found everything except my "job complete" trace was being written.  I add a 2 minute wait for safety.  This may have been fixed but worth checking.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to inject your instrumentation key in your log4net.config you can pass it in the AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry method:

```
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(new ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions
        {
            ConnectionString = Configuration["ApplicationInsights:ConnectionString"],
            EnableActiveTelemetryConfigurationSetup = true
        });
```

(Using the connection string is prefered over the telemetry key now.
)

It should work as long as you have the log4netappender package
[image]

And app insights should be configured as an appender

```
  <appender name="aiAppender" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Log4NetAppender.ApplicationInsightsAppender, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Log4NetAppender">
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%message%newline"/>
    </layout>
  </appender>
```